# List with numbers, whose digits are only 2, 4, 6

Tags: haskell

The task is to generate list with numbers, whose digits are only 2,4,6.

*Example*:[2,4,6,22,24,26,42,44,46,62,64,66,222,224,226,...]

I have already solved this task via brute force:

```
numberHasOnly246 :: Integer -> Bool
numberHasOnly246 0 = False
numberHasOnly246 n = result 
  where
    result = helper True (abs n)
helper :: Bool -> Integer -> Bool
helper result n 
  | (div n 10 == 0) = condition && result
  | (div n 10 > 0)  = helper (condition && result) (div n 10) 
  where
    condition = mod n 10 == 4 || mod n 10 == 6 || mod n 10 == 2

series246 :: [Integer]
series246 = numbers[1..] 
  where
    numbers(e : ls) = e : (numbers [ x | x <- ls, (numberHasOnly246 x == True)])
```

But it seems that this solution is too slow.
Also, I've read, that there is tying the knot method for generating infinite lists in Haskell, but here I cannot find how to solve it via tying the knot. Is this method suitable here?

Comment: instead of generating and testing, you can simply generate numbers in such a way that it contains 2, 4, and 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a generate-and-test approach, you can only generate numbers that are valid.

For a single digit this is thus:

```
digits :: [Int]
digits = [2, 4, 6]
```

for numbers, we can make use of recursion here:

```
numbers = [ 10*t + d | t <- (0:numbers), d <- digits ]
```

Here `t` is thus the values we multiply with 10, and we start with `0`. `d` are the digits that we then can append. This thus gives us:

```
Prelude> numbers
[2,4,6,22,24,26,42,44,46,62,64,66,222,224,226,242,244,246,262,264,266,422,424,426,442, …
```